# Regex excluding specific character

Tags: regex

I wonder if it's possible to exclude character or skip more specific to skip them if they exist. I have JSON file like:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "array1": [
    {
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4"
    },
    {
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6"
    },
    {
      "key7":"value7",
      "key8":"value8"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to get output in regex like:

```
{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}
{"key5":"value5","key6":"value6"}
{"key7":"value7","key8":"value8"}
```

My first version of regex is:

```
"array1":\[(\{[A-za-z0-9%,:."]+})+
```

I don't know how to skip "," character if it exists.
To simplify it I work on JSON without whitespaces:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","array1":[{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"},{"key5":"value5","key6":"value6"},{"key7":"value7","key8":"value8"}]}
```

So I don't know if it's possible to do what I want with regex or I should just return array1 and process it with for example java to split to strings.

Comment: Why not `replace(/},/g, '}\n')`?

Comment: Smart one, I didn't think about replacing ","...

Comment: Isn't it easier to use a tool that can parse the JSON and convert it into data structures that can be easily modified then exported back as JSON(s)? `regex` is not the most appropriate tool to modify JSON-encoded content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the unwanted character:

```js
str = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","array1":[{"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"},{"key5":"value5","key6":"value6"},{"key7":"value7","key8":"value8"}]}';
str = str.split('[');
newStr = str[1].replace(/},/g, '}\n').replace('}]', '');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Yea I will have to do like that, I was hoping I can do everything in regex but seems it's not created that way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not the best tool for this job.

A simple PHP script that decodes the JSON and operates on the data always produces the correct result and it is also able to detect invalid input:

```
$json = << END
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "array1": [
    {
      "key3":"value3",
      "key4":"value4"
    },
    {
      "key5":"value5",
      "key6":"value6"
    },
    {
      "key7":"value7",
      "key8":"value8"
    }
  ]
}
END;

$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($data['array1'] as $value) {
     echo json_encode($value), "\n";
}
```

Validation is not included in the code above but it can be easily added by checking the value returned by [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) against `NULL`.